# Find column vector sum for a binary matrix which is arranged in maximal form using a given row vector sum

Tags: c++, math, matrix, vector, sum

For a mxn binary matrix, row vector sum is given as (r<sub>1</sub>,r<sub>2</sub>...r<sub>i</sub> ) where i in (1 to n).. which means count of numbers of ones(1) in row 1 is r<sub>1</sub>, row 2 is r<sub>2</sub>.. and row m is r<sub>m</sub>.
Now in the given matrix 1's are arranged in maximal form.. i.e for each row first r<sub>i</sub> cells contain 1 and remaining cells r<sub>i+1</sub> to r<sub>n</sub> contains zero.

Now for the matrix of above form number of ones in each column is to be calculated... which will be called as column vector sum. 

Solution with complexity o(mn) is already there

If given a 6x5 matrix with row vector sum as R = (3,4,5,2,3).
using this create a binary matrix of maximal form:
3-->|1 1 1 0 0 0|
4-->|1 1 1 1 0 0|
5-->|1 1 1 1 1 0|
2-->|1 1 0 0 0 0|
3-->|1 1 1 0 0 0|

Now calculate the column sum vector.. for the above example it will be 
C = (5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0)

Current Code:

```
int m = 5;
int n = 6;
int row[m] = {3,4,5,2,3};//given: value in this array will always be <=n
int column_maximalColumnVector[n];// initialised to zero
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row[i]; j++) {
        column_maximalColumnVector[j]++;

    }
 }
```

Comment: This approach (if I interprete it correctly) has `O(m*n)` complexity. Do you expect better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m = 5;
    int n = 6;

    int row[m] = { 3, 4, 5, 2, 3 }; //given: value in this array will always be <=n

    int k = sizeof(row) / sizeof(row[0]);
    sort(row, row + m);

    int steps = row[0];
    int row_count = 0;
    int col_count = 0;
    int maximal_vector_value = m;
    int column_maximalColumnVector[n] = { 0 }; // initialised to zero

    while (row_count <= m - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            column_maximalColumnVector[col_count++] = maximal_vector_value;
        }

        maximal_vector_value -= 1;
        if ((row_count + 1) < m) {
            steps = row[row_count + 1] - row[row_count];
        }
        row_count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```